# He has just been offered or he was offered

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect

What are the differences in meaning between these two sentences:

> 1. He *was just offered* a well-paid job with Radio Four. (Past Simple Passive)
> 2. He *has just been offered* a well-paid job with Radio Four. (Present Perfect Passive)

Both are grammatically correct, but what are the real meaning if I use #1 / #2?

Comment: @PartTimer Please read through [this FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask). The questions that you have asked before should be listed on your profile page ...

Comment: Is this American English or British English?

Comment: This is British English. Is this the reason why both sentences have different meaning to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but (1) is not idiomatic usage in British English.

> 1. <s>He was just offered a well-paid job with Radio Four.</s>
> 2. He has just been offered a well-paid job with Radio Four.

British English speakers might use the active form:

> 1. I have just offered him a well-paid job with Radio Four.
> 2. *(colloq.)* I just offered him that job!

I believe the reason is that *He was offered* connotes an event some time in the past, and contradicting that with *just* sounds odd. It's understood though, probably because it is used thus in American English (I believe).

Comment: Might not *he was just offered* mean *he was only offered*?

Comment: @Tim Yes, but in the context of the question which matches (1) and (2) as broadly equivalent, it doesn't :-)

Comment: I'd disagree that "He was just offered..." is not ideomatic. It's not quite as common as "He has just been offered..." but it's used often enough where I live (English North Midlands) to be familiar. To me "He was just offered..." sounds as though the offer was in the immediate past (maybe he's just come out of his performance review meeting) as opposed to "He has just been offered..." which _could_ apply on that timescale but could also still be used a couple of days later.

Answer (score 1):

"He has just been offered a well-paid job with Radio Four" sounds more recent and has the intended effect in terms of communicating the timing of the offer. It uses the right tense as the present perfect tense is used to talk about events that occurred very recently.

"He was just offered a well-paid job with Radio Four" sounds a bit awkward and doesn't effectively tell the listener about when exactly the job was offered - recently or sometime in the past.