# Do 'already' and 'just' require the present perfect?

Tags: adverbs, present-perfect

Compare:

> 'We already/just gave him a response'.
>
> 'We have already/just given him a response'.

Do 'already' and 'just' strictly require the present perfect?

Comment: Formally, yes; colloquially, no; and the colloquial usage will probably be formally acceptable within a generation.

Comment: Not even formally.  _Already_ and _just_ are complex temporal adverbs, but adverbs do not govern constructions; verbs do. In this case, there is no reason to require a perfect construction, though it's acceptable, as is the past tense.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76800/he-has-just-been-offered-or-he-was-offered British English **does** use the present perfect, almost exclusively.

Comment: @Andrew Leach ... then John Lawler is wrong(!?).

Comment: Far be it from me to contradict a linguistics professor! This is one of the differences between American English and British English.

Comment: @JohnLawler I shall have to be more careful: *formal* doesn't mean quite the same thing to a literary scholar as it does to a linguist. Although well-formed, "Milton already gave us his context in the preceding line" would have been regarded by the professors of my youth as unacceptably colloquial in a formal essay.

Comment: Is the discussion about "formally"? I meant formal grammar, of course, since the discussion is about grammar (I take "require the present perfect" to be a term of grammatical art). In formal grammar, one must account for all and only the grammatical utterances, and specify precisely in which contexts and under which circumstances every construction is required, forbidden, or optional. Both the Past Tense and the Present Perfect Construction are optional with _already_, and with _just_, in these senses. That's all.

Comment: Even in British English, the past tense is possible with ‘already’ in some contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, get the tense right for the purpose, then add *just, already, yet, not yet, still, no longer, any more* as appropriate.

If your purpose is to give news to someone, you will probably use present perfect in UK, past simple in US.

There is often a choice. E.g. *we (have) already stopped sending her flowers* = *we no longer send her flowers* = *we don't send her flowers any more*.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the past tense in this construction, especially when spoken, is often used to express emphasis and, perhaps frustration.

> We already GAVE him a response.
>
> We just GAVE him a response.

These forms are used to indicate that the recipient is somehow not being reasonable in continuing to seek further feedback. The sentences would have less "punch" if they were delivered as

> We HAVE ALREADY GIVEN him a response.
>
> We HAVE JUST GIVEN him a response.

Comment: Counter-point:  "We already send her flowers every week.  Do we need to send a card, too?"

Comment: Present tense works for emphasis too. *We already SEND her flowers . . .* Much better than *We HAVE ALREADY BEEN SENDING her flowers . . .*

Answer (score -1):

For me, such adverbs as "so far, not yet, already, just, recently, ever + superlative, to date etc" 
DO require a Present Perfect, even if I've heard Americans using the Past Tense. To express "emphasis or frustration" - as argued above - the intonation and the sentence stress will do that.

Comment: In general, yes.  But not always.  There are some verbs that it is not necessary for.  Before answering, you probably want to do more research and provide a more detailed answer using some links.